# View Controller Transparent Background

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

How can I create a view controller with a transparent background that overlays another view controller where the bottom view controller is still visible in iOS 9? The way that works in iOS 8 no longer works.

Comment: @Lorenzo, you should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Lorenzo, I'm confused about 'yes but...'. Is the answer to short?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you can set overlaid view controller's background colour as clear colour.

You can use presentViewController method to overlay new view controller.

This from apple docs

When presenting a view controller using the **UIModalPresentationFullScreen** style, UIKit normally removes the views of the underlying view controller after the transition animations finish. You can prevent the removal of those views by specifying the **UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen** style instead.

So you can set overlaid view controller's **modalPresentationStyle** to **UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen**

I also hope this may be help

When using one of the full-screen presentation styles, the view controller that initiates the presentation must itself cover the entire screen. If the presenting view controller does not cover the screen, UIKit walks up the view controller hierarchy until it finds one that does. If it can’t find an intermediate view controller that fills the screen, UIKit uses the root view controller of the window.

Comment: If you used UIPopoverController, it is deprecated in iOS9.0

Comment: Thank you however this still does not work. Once the view controller settles on top of the other controller the bottom views disappear leaving a black background.

Answer (score 0):

[image: You have to choose the "Cover Vertical" option on the Transition Style on your ViewController.]

[image: And on the View inside the ViewController the alpha desired.]

To solve this problem you just have to change the Alpha information of your View. To get this view on top of others, change the Transition Style of the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: The syntax is now:

```
        childVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
```

Comment: I'm confused how this relates to the asked question?

Comment: Please expand your answer. "the syntax" - of what? Your line does not actually create the view controller. Perhaps a few more lines of code would clarify what you mean.